# Pick array with .shift

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a shuffled array representing cards.
Now I need to pick 2-5 'cards' from the array 'myDeck' and display them.
Do I use a loop for that?

Right now I use multiple instances of the variable:

```
let shifted = myDeck.shift()
let shifted2 = myDeck.shift()
```

and for display purpose I use the simple:

```
console.log(shifted + shifted2)
```

So instead of doing this, which works. Could I use a loop instead?
Like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  myDeck.shift += i
  return myDeck }
```

Or how can i get about this?

Thank you very much in advance. Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to take items from one array, and assign to another array:

```js
var myDeck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// remove 3 items starting from index 0, and assign to picked
var picked = myDeck.splice(0, 3); 

console.log('myDeck: ', myDeck.join());

console.log('picked: ', picked.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you already have a "shuffled" deck, just take however many cards you need off the top:

```
var x = 2 // or 5, however many you want
var myCards = myDeck.slice(0, x);
console.log(myCards);
```